# Security in apex.server.process in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle, oracle-apex

After disabling a button using JavaScript (Client), we are trying to create a record in a DB table through an Ajax (On-Demand Process) call. User can easily make a similar call from browser console and create a record. How do we prevent this?

In general, are ajax calls made using apex.server.process secure? How do we secure them?

Would be grateful if you can help.
Thanks

Comment: Does your APEX application use an Authentication scheme?  If so, you can configure things so that APEX will only allow AJAX calls that have the correct session information to be accepted by APEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Authorization Scheme or server side condition on your ajax process.
I suggest you to disable the button using server side condition.